# Automatically use list of figure entry in caption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

Using the optional argument for `\caption` it is possible to change the entry placed into a list of figures. The style I use in my thesis always has a "header" or "title" for a figure, i.e. a short part of the caption that I print in bold using `textbf`. This is in my case always the same as what I put into the optional argument of my captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption[The universe]{\textbf{The Universe}\\Some very long description of this image that should not be in the list of figures...}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now I have `The universe` both as the entry in the list of figures and as a bold line at the beginning of the caption. Is there any way to achieve this automatically though? It often happens that I accidentally change only one or the other, e.g. ending up with

```
\caption[Something new]{\textbf{The Universe}\\Some very long description of this image that should not be in the list of figures...}
```

Where now `Something new` != `The Universe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new command `\captionx`

```
\newcommand{\captionx}[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1}\\ #2}}
```

to be used as

```
\captionx{Something new!}{Some very long description of this image that should not be in the list of figures...}
```

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\captionx}[2]{\caption[#1]{\textbf{#1}\\ #2}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \caption[The universe]{\textbf{The Universe}\\Some very long description of this image that should not be in the list of figures...}        
        \label{fig:universe}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
       \centering
       \includegraphics{example-image-b}
       \captionx{Something new!}{Some very long description of this image that should not be in the list of figures...} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
       \label{fig:new}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: And here I was digging through the caption package's documentation trying to find a way to solve this with a package option or similar and didn't even think about just making it into a newcommand.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)